# Slow to_json with oj gem in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, to-json

I upgraded my Rails app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2. The to_json performance in my views is terrible. In my Rails 3.2 app I used multi_json and the Oj gem to get great performance. With Rails 4.2 I setup the oj gem this way:

```
gem 'oj', '~> 2.14', '>= 2.14.2'
gem 'oj_mimic_json', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
```

However, the to_json performance doesn't seem to be nearly as good as with the Rails 3.2 app. One to_json call takes about 50% of CPU time.

The Oj gem documentation mentions adding:

```
serialize :metadata, Oj
```

to make it work with ActiveRecord. Is this line supposed to go in the models that I use?

[image]

Comment: The `serialize :metadata, Oj` goes into attributes that use JSON serialization in my opinion. I still don't know how to use the gem with rails to replace default json. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Sadly I'm still having the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer mentioned here:
https://github.com/ohler55/oj/issues/199

After adding both gems, one also has to call:

```
Oj.mimic_JSON()
```

For `.to_json` to use Oj.